# XML and XSL cannot display

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSL. Im using IE9, both files are at the location. When I tried to drag my .xml to the browser, it does not show anything

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="catalog.xsl"?>
<CATALOG>
<CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
</CD>
</CATALOG>
```

and the XSL:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Artist</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
            <tr>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="TITLE" />
              </td>
              <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="ARTIST" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm behind a proxy which is stopping me from accessing the XSL file

Comment: I've edited your question to incorporate your XSL, rather than linking so that @Houtman and others can see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xpath expressions are case-sensitive; try replacing your:

```
<xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
```

with:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CATALOG/CD">
```

Comment: wow! Thanks, its a great relief. Ive been working on it for almost 2hours.

Comment: Also, you're missing the namespace declaration on your stylesheet; the first line should be `<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">`. One thing to consider is using a browser which gives more helpful error messages with problematic XSL -- Firefox and Opera are both better than IE, in my experience, often taking you straight to the root of the problem.